# vegan package installation error in R i386 3.1.0 version

Tags: r, vegan

I am using R i386 3.0.1 version. I want to use vegan package. When I typed

```
library(vegan)
```

I got the following message:

```
Error in library (vegan): there is no package called ‘vegan’
```

I have used vegan package in R i386 3.0.1 version before, but recently I am using new pc and when I wanted to download vegan package in R i386 3.1.0 version I got this problem. I am rather new to R, and failed to find any explanation of this error.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What happens when you try `install.packages("vegan")`? BTW: please be careful when copy/pasting code: you used `Library` with an upper-case "L", which is not going to give you that error. It's not that I mind seeing it mis-spelled, it's that often that one (if not all) of the sources of problem are due to spelling or argument usage, and having you type it "fresh" into the window completely masks that problem. It is better to copy it directly from the console (even if simple) to make sure we can see that type of error. Also, it helps to format it well: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: One more thing ... R-3.1.0? That version is 4 years old, is there a reason you are not using R-3.3, R-3.4, or (perhaps too-recently released) R-3.5?

Comment: The error message seems to tell that you have not installed vegan. When you upgrade R and have a new PC, you need to install the add-on packages as well. For R 3.1.0 you should be able to install vegan 3.4-6.

Comment: When I use the latest version of R I got errors for my codes that I have used in R-3-1.0. I do not know how to resolve it. in the newest version of R I can download vegan package but my previous codes get errors

Comment: How can I install add-on package on my R-3-1-0??

Comment: `install.packages("vegan")` then post any errors; it may well be that binaries for your system just aren't available. If that is the case, upgrade your R to a newer version.